# It seems somebody pursuits me.

Tags: discussion

In just one minute I received 7 downvotes in 7 different questions. It is quite obvious to me that I am a victim of pursuit of a user.

-2      21 mins ago     downvote    What is the difference between a measurement and any other interaction in quantum mechanics?

-2  22 mins ago     downvote    Is Angular Momentum truly fundamental?

-2  23 mins ago     downvote    What is information?

-2  23 mins ago     downvote    Do all massive bodies emit Hawking radiation?

-2  23 mins ago     downvote    Popular depictions of electromagnetic wave: is there an error?

-2  24 mins ago     downvote    What do you think about teaching Standard Model in school?

-2  24 mins ago     downvote    What is the wavefunction of the observer himself?

Is this type of behavior allowed in Stackexchange?

Comment: I checked the history of all my vocal opponents and it seems that none of them made all these downvotes. This may suggest that the downvotings were made from a specially-created account.

Comment: Don't discount the possibility that, by posting, you've drawn the attentions of a *lot* of people, and that a few of them when to look at your work and cast one or two votes.

Comment: a specially-created account does not have the privilege to downvote, you need 125 rep to do so

Comment: People operate in groups or in "packs". If the leader of the flock takes a dislike to something then it is inevitable that the minions will follow. But don't worry. There are many good people also. Take a down-vote not as a rebuke of your intellect but as a sighting of a member of a pack. @dmckee it is the timing of the votes that makes the list seem suspicious.

Comment: Seems it has been reversed automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this type of behavior allowed in Stackexchange?

No, it isn't. There are automatic algorithms in place to detect serial downvoting and reverse the votes cast. See [this Stack Exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) for more info.

Comment: So may I hope that these will be reversed?

Comment: Yep, if they do constitute a pattern of serial downvoting against you, they should be reversed within 24 hours. If after that time you still see the downvotes, it probably means that it was just a coincidence in which several users downvoted you within a short timespan.

Comment: @anixx if they are not reversed in 24-36 hours feel free to email us at the address at the bottom of every web page.